# How to obtain the Tensorflow code version of a NN built in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have been working with Keras for a week or so. I know that Keras can use either TensorFlow or Theano as a backend. In my case, I am using TensorFlow.

So I'm wondering: is there a way to write a NN in Keras, and then print out the equivalent version in TensorFlow?

**MVE**

For instance suppose I write

```
    #create seq model
    model = Sequential()
    # add layers
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = (10,), activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
    # fit
    model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
    # predict
    ypred = model.predict(Xtest, batch_size = 32)
    # evaluate
    result = model.evaluate(Xtest)
```

This code might be wrong, since I just started, but I think you get the idea.

What I want to do is write down this code, run it (or not even, maybe!) and then have a function or something that will produce the TensorFlow code that Keras has written to do all these calculations.

Comment: Why don't you learn tensorflow then? It would surely be beneficial for you... If you take the time to learn Keras you can learn tensorflow :) But surely this is not an answer to your question... My experience is that with conversion tools you almost never get a good result (if such a tool exists)...

Comment: Additionally some google search got me the following results worth checking: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3223 and especially http://www.pythonexample.com/code/convert-keras-to-tensorflow/

Comment: Thank you! I am trying very hard to learn in (although just a few hours), however I can't seem to find someone showing how to build an MLP for regression. Everyone focuses on classification. This is a minor problem. Another problem is that they use datasets which are already in TensorFlow and thus they have some built-in methods or functions. I could find this: http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/python-tensorflow-tutorial/#comment-3451 which is really good, but I can't seem to modify it using my own dataset..

Comment: Do you know of any good resource where I could find such a MLP in TensorFlow? Ideally, I would like to build a MLP for regression that instead of using the dot product between the output of the previous layer and the weights, it uses the cosine similarity (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05870.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean exactly with MLP? Just to be clear... Multi Layer Perceptron?

Comment: Yes a multi layer perceptron!

Comment: I know I can use MLPRegressor in Scikit-learn, however there is no way of using cosine similarity instead of the dot product..

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted so that others know what answer/information was useful. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clarify some of the language in the question. TensorFlow (and Theano) use computational graphs to perform tensor computations. So, when you ask if there is a way to "print out the equivalent version" in Tensorflow, or "produce TensorFlow code," what you're really asking is, **how do you export a TensorFlow graph from a Keras model?**

As the Keras author states in [this thread](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3223),

> When you are using the TensorFlow backend, your Keras code is actually building a TF graph. You can just grab this graph.
>
> Keras only uses one graph and one session.

However, he links to [a tutorial whose details are now outdated](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html). But the basic concept has not changed.

We just need to:

- Get the TensorFlow session
- Export the computation graph from the TensorFlow session

#### Do it with Keras

The [keras_to_tensorflow](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow/blob/master/keras_to_tensorflow.ipynb) repository contains a short example of how to export a model from Keras for use in TensorFlow in an iPython notebook. This is basically using TensorFlow. It isn't a clearly-written example, but throwing it out there as a resource.

#### Do it with TensorFlow

It turns out we can actually **get the TensorFlow session that Keras is using from TensorFlow itself**, using the [tf.contrib.keras.backend.get_session()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/backend/get_session) function. It's pretty simple to do - just import and call. This returns the TensorFlow session.

Once you have the TensorFlow session variable, you can use the SavedModelBuilder to save your computational graph ([guide + example to using SavedModelBuilder in the TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic)). If you're wondering how the SavedModelBuilder works and what it actually gives you, the [SavedModelBuilder Readme in the Github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) is a good guide.

P.S. - If you are planning on heavy usage of TensorFlow + Keras in combination, have a look at the other modules available in [tf.contrib.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use instead of WX+b a different function for your neurons. Well in tensorflow you explicitly calculate this product, so for example you do

```
y_ = tf.matmul(X, W)
```

you simply have to write your formula and let the network learn. It should not be difficult to implement.

In addition what you are trying to do (according to the paper you link) is called batch normalization and is relatively standard. The idea being you normalize your intermediate steps (in the different layers). Check for example https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwikh-HM7PnWAhXDXRQKHZJhD9EQFggyMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1502.03167&usg=AOvVaw1nGzrGnhPhNGEczNwcn6WK or https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwikh-HM7PnWAhXDXRQKHZJhD9EQFghCMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbcourses.berkeley.edu%2Ffiles%2F66022277%2Fdownload%3Fdownload_frd%3D1%26verifier%3DoaU8pqXDDwZ1zidoDBTgLzR8CPSkWe6MCBKUYan7&usg=AOvVaw0AHLwD_0pUr1BSsiiRoIFc

Hope that helps,
Umberto

Comment: yes so instead of having $h = f(\textbf{W}^T\textbf{X} + \textbf{b})$ as the output of a layer, we would have $h = f(\frac{\textbf{W^TX}}{|\textbf{W}|, |\text{X}|})$

Comment: Yeah something like that. I will try to put together an example for you to check... Just give me some time :)

Comment: Thank you very much if you could do something like that, it would be awesome. Looking online, quite some people are looking for this kind of example!

Comment: If I can dare to give a suggestion, if you could do even a small Multi Layer Perceptron (2 hidden layers would be just fine), with relu activation function on all of them (since we are doing regression) and using the cosine similarity , that would be perfect!

Comment: And if possible, would you be able to not use one of those datasets that you can download from tensorflow?

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot. Good luck writing down the example anyway! And thanks again